# Adding hover effect to a specific portion of the nav bar

Tags: css, hover, navbar

Here I have a working nav bar with a drop down menu. However I want two different hover effects on both the main nav bar and a different one for the drop down menu, I already have the main nav bar working with a hover effect by adding the below CSS code.

```
#nav_bar a:hover { 
                 background:#8c1b1f;
                 padding-bottom:13px;
                 padding-top:17px;
                 padding-left:10px;
                 padding-right:10px;                               
                 }
```

I simply need a way of adding a separate hover effect to the drop down menu

Comment: Please create a code snippet including html part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use CSS here this way:

```
#nav_bar>ul>li>a:hover {
      //styles here for main menu hover
}

#nav_bar>ul>li>ul>li>a:hover {
      //styles here for dropdown menu hover
}
```

So your CSS for the main menu hover will become:

```
#nav_bar>ul>li>a:hover {
     background:#8c1b1f;
     padding-bottom:13px;
     padding-top:17px;
     padding-left:10px;
     padding-right:10px; 
}
```

And you can use the following code to specify CSS for the dropdown menu hover:

```
#nav_bar>ul>li>ul>li>a:hover {
      //styles here for dropdown menu hover
}
```

```css
#nav_bar {
  background-color: #a22b2f;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px;
}
#nav_bar ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
#nav_bar ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#nav_bar ul li a {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px;
}
#nav_bar ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
#nav_bar ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0px;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#nav_bar ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
#nav_bar ul li:hover ul li a {
  color: black;
}
#nav_bar>ul>li>a:hover {
  color: blue;
  background: #fff;
}
#nav_bar>ul>li>ul>li>a:hover {
  color: red;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav_bar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="status.html">STATUS</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="info.html">INFO</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">GAMEMODES</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">GAMEMODE - SURVIVAL</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">GAMEMODE - PURE-PVP</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">GAMEMODE - GAMESWORLD</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="rules.html">RULES</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="vote.html">VOTE</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks again! Is there any way I can give you a rating?

Comment: I have more more query, can I ask?